# Django/JavaScript button click shows value - reload page removes value

Tags: javascript, django

I'm creating a game in Django more specifically in oTree with a Django Template Language and JavaScript frontend. When I click a button a value needs to be shown (got that covered) this is done with some JavaScript. But when I refresh/reload the page I need that value to still be displayed and not click the button all over. Does anybody know if there is a workaround for this in either Django or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state of the show/hidden values must be stored somewhere: either client-side (browser) or server-side. For client-side storing, you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), for server-side - [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/), [DB](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/#the-model-layer) or [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/). If you decide to use server-side state - add some more js to buttons `onclick` event handlers and send state of the button to the server by ajax